# persistentvolumeclaim not found in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Currently i try to implement **PersistentVolume** in my yaml file . 
I read a lot of documentation on internet and i dont understand why when i go to the dashboard pod i've  this message

> persistentvolumeclaim "karaf-conf" not found

pod.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: karafpod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: karaf
    image: xxx/karaf:ids-1.1.0
    volumeMounts:
    - name: karaf-conf-storage
      mountPath: "/apps/karaf/etc"
  volumes:
    - name: karaf-conf-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: karaf-conf-claim
```

**PersistentVolumeClaimKaraf.yml**

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: karaf-conf-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Mi
```

**PersistentVolume.yaml**

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: karaf-conf
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 100Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/apps/karaf/etc"
```

You will find below the result of the command **kubectl get pv**

```
NAME                             CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS        CLAIM                         STORAGECLASS   REASON    AGE
karaf-conf                    100Mi      RWO            Retain           Terminating   default/karaf-conf-claim                            17h
karaf-conf-persistentvolume   100Mi      RWO            Retain           Released      default/karaf-conf                                  1h
```

**kubectl get pvc**

```
NAME                  STATUS        VOLUME          CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
karaf-conf-claim   Terminating   karaf-conf   10Mi       RWO            manual         17h
```

Comment: Can you expand question with output of `kubectl get pv karaf-conf-persistentvolume -o yaml` ?

Answer (score 5):

With hostPath, you don't need PersistentVolume or PersistentVolumeClaim objects, so this might be easier depending on your need:

```yaml
# file: pod.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: karafpod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: karaf
    image: xxx/karaf:ids-1.1.0
    volumeMounts:
    - name: karaf-conf-storage
      mountPath: "/apps/karaf/etc"  # Path mounted in container

  # Use hostPath here
  volumes:
    - name: karaf-conf-storage
      hostPath:
        path: "/apps/karaf/etc" # Path from the host
```

Then delete the other two .yaml files `PersistentVolumeClaimKaraf.yml` and `PersistentVolume.yml`

For official documentation, see: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath

Edit: Noticed that spec.containers.VolumeMounts.mountPath and spec.containers.volumes.hostPath.path from the original post were the same, so added comments in yaml to clarify purpose of each.

Comment: That's much easier than what is described here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/

Comment: `HostPath volumes present many security risks, and it is a best practice to avoid the use of HostPaths when possible. When a HostPath volume must be used, it should be scoped to only the required file or directory, and mounted as ReadOnly.`

Answer (score 1):

I think that root cause of your issue is related with `Terminating` state.

As fast fix for this issue, you should create new PV and PVC (with different name than those in `Terminating` state.

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: karaf-conf-new
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 100Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/apps/karaf/etc"
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: karaf-conf-newclaim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Mi
```

Edit your `Pod` yaml to use new `claimName`:

```
  volumes:
    - name: karaf-conf-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: karaf-conf-newclaim
```

When `PersistentVolumeClaim` is in 'Terminating' state, it suggests that you deleted a `PVC` being in active use by some Pod.
The thing is that you find your self now in dead-lock state, in other words your 'karafpod' Pod won't start up unless a referenced `PVC` is in Bound state.

From your outputs, I can see that there is `karaf-conf-persistentvolume` PV which was bouned to PVC: `karaf-conf`. I would guess that you have tried to delete `PVCs`.

As your `PersistentVolumes` have [ReclaimPolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#reclaiming) set to [Retain](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#retain), `PVC: karaf-conf` was removed without issues as it was not used by any `Pods` and due to that policy, `PV: karaf-conf-persistentvolume` was kept.

However, your `pod: karafpod` claimed `PVC: karaf-conf-claim` which was bounded to `PV: karaf-conf`. As this pod was running, `PVC` and `PV` couldn't be removed.

Fix if you would like to keep all names the same.

1. Delete `pod: karafpod`, you can use `--grace-period` to fore it.
   `kubectl delete pod <PODNAME> --grace-period=0 --force`
2. Delete`PVC: karaf-conf-claim`  and `PV: karaf-conf`.
3. Check if PV and PVC was removed.
   `kubectl get pv,pvc`

You can also check for Pods that are actively using PVC. It can be achieved using command from [this thread](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/65233#issuecomment-512090013)

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o=json | jq -c '.items[] | {name: .metadata.name, namespace: .metadata.namespace, claimName: .spec |  select( has ("volumes") ).volumes[] | select( has ("persistentVolumeClaim") ).persistentVolumeClaim.claimName }'
```

4. Create `PVC: karaf-conf-claim`  and `PV: karaf-conf`
5. Deploy `pod: karafpod`

Answer (score 0):

pv/karaf-conf is in terminating status, try to delete it and recreate it using `type: DirectoryOrCreate`.

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: karaf-conf
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 100Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/apps/karaf/etc"
    type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is recreating `pv` and `pvc`, and you ensure you are running the pod on the node host that configured the `hostPath`.

Comment: When i try to delete the pv or pvc with **kubectl delete pvc/XXX** it say  persistentvolume "karaf-conf" deleted. but when i run 
**kubectl delete pvc/XXX** it's steel here :(